# Is bounded finite set theory equivalent to bounded arithmetic?

Tags: set-theory, arithmetic, first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

Bounded finite set theory is:

Extensionality + $\Delta_0$-Separation + Adjunction?

Where *Adjunction* is: $\forall x \forall y \ (x \cup \{y\} \text { exists})$

> Would this theory be equivalent to bounded arithmetic?

Comment: Is your question motivated by [Kirby's presentation?](https://nylogic.github.io/mopa/2020/05/13/bounded-finite-set-theory.html)

Comment: @HanulJeon, I didn't know anything about that. My question is primarily motivated by the equivalence of $\sf Q$ with adjunctive sets theory (i.e. $\emptyset$ exists + Adjunction). Now clearly if we add separation to adjunctive set theory then we get PA. That's why I thought if restricting separation to bounded separation, then this *might* interpret bounded arithmetic.